# is it possible to change delivery depending upon product

Tags: magento2, magento-1, delivery

I am trying to figure out if magento will provide me with all the functionality I need or if I have to write some code specifically. Naturally I'd like to keep the system as standard as possible. What I need to do is set the shop up with free delivery unless specific items have been ordered alone. So for example if we have two items in the shop:

Item A - 50p cost and is 50p to deliver on it's own otherwise no extra fee with item B.
Item B - £4.50 cost and is 50p to deliver

Now in the shop I will mark item B as £5 with free delivery. What I would like is to sell item A at 50p and then this happens.

Item A and Item B in cart = free delivery.
Item A in cart alone = 50p delivery.

Is there a way of doing this or will I have to use something like Checkout_Cart_Save_Before and alter it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use a cart price rule. Set up the condition to trigger when Article B is in cart (or the combination A and B, to your liking). Set a 0% discount and choose the option "Free of delivery".
Remember to keep the cart price rules applied and that should work about fine.